# How can I use GTK notebook to add tabs to my browser?

Tags: c, webkit, gtk

I'm new to C and am trying to build a web browser using GTK, but I just can't get tabs to work!
I think this is the relevant code:

```
#include<gtk/gtk.h>

GtkWidget *window;
GtkWidget *vbox;
GtkWidget *hbox;
GtkWidget *scrollable_window;
GtkWidget *new_tab_button;
GtkWidget *tab_label;
GtkWidget *notebook;

void new_tab() {
gtk_notebook_append_page(GTK_NOTEBOOK(notebook), scrollable_window, tab_label); 
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
gtk_widget_set_size_request(GTK_WIDGET(window), 1300, 768);
tab_label = gtk_label_new ("tab");
scrollable_window = gtk_scrolled_window_new(NULL,NULL);
vbox = gtk_vbox_new(false,false);
hbox = gtk_hbox_new(false,false);
hbox_web_view = gtk_hbox_new(true,0);

notebook = gtk_notebook_new ();
gtk_notebook_set_tab_pos (GTK_NOTEBOOK (notebook), GTK_POS_TOP);
gtk_widget_show(notebook);

gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), scrollable_window);
gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(scrollable_window), vbox);
gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(vbox), hbox);
gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(vbox), hbox_web_view);

new_tab_button = gtk_button_new_with_label("New tab");

g_signal_connect(new_tab_button, "clicked", G_CALLBACK(new_tab), web);
gtk_widget_show_all(window);

gtk_main();
return 0;
```

Everything works, but there is no notebook showing when I open the program. There is a 'new tab' button but whenever I click it it closes the program!

I think I just don't quite understand how gtk notebooks work. Could anyone help me out?

Comment: You have to add it to some container, don't you? Well you didn't. I can't tell you where to add it, because I can't follow your widget hierarchy.

Comment: Iharob I just get the 'Can't set a parent on widget which has a parent' error no matter where I add it.

Comment: Also, using global variables is bad, and it indicates that you don't understand how *gtk*'s API is designed to prevent this. Read the documentation more carefully until you understand their model.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do I get a segmentation fault in my GTK+ signal callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48200255/why-do-i-get-a-segmentation-fault-in-my-gtk-signal-callback)

Answer (score 0):

Your code indicates that you are just calling functions without reasoning why you should or not call each function.

The `gtk_container_add()` adds a widget to another widget that can be a container, i.e. that can contain other widgets, e.g. a `GtkBox` or the `GtkWindow` itself.

You are creating the notebook correctly, but you don't add it to any container in the widget hierarchy that has `window` as it's natural root.

Also, you create a `scrollable_window` only once but in real life — unless your design is optimizing memory and you know what you're doing — you need multiple `scrollable_window` instances, in fact you need a web view and all the children you're adding in your code to the `window` container.

Having mulitple instances of `scrollable_window` means that you should create each instance in your `new_tab()` callback, which BTW has a wrong signature, I don't know which the right signature is but it's certainly not that.

Usually GTK gives you

- The object that generated the signal as the first parameter of the callback.
- A pointer to your own data, that you can use to avoid global variables and make your code more robust and reusable.
- There are some callbacks that have extra parameters, you just need to see the signal's documentation to determine which is the correct signature.
- Some callbacks (*if not all, I don't remember*) return a `gboolean` to indicate whether or not your callback handled the event.

Ideally then,

1. Create the notebook.
2. Add the notebook directly to the `window` container, it should be your root widget.
3. Create a "*browser*" in your  `new_tab()` callback, and add it to your notebook. Use the first parameter which is mostly sure of type `GtkWidget` and is a pointer to your notebook thus eliminating the need for it to be global, don't use global variables, ever.
4. Use the `gpointer data` — probably the last parameter to your callback — to store any *context* data that you need to share with your `main()` function.

   The ideal way to achieve independency, and completely avoid global variables is to create a structure to store your application state, although modern Gtk+ has mechanisms for this, it's still a good idea to store your data somewhere and pass it around to callbacks via the last parameter to `g_signal_connect()` and receive it as the last parameter to your callbacks.