# Callback function for "delete-event" signal passes incorrect values of variables

Tags: c, gtk, gtk3

Whenever I pass something to a callback function when `"delete-event"` is triggered with intention to clean something when the window is quit, values that I send get corrupt.

For example, here is a small program that illustrates this problem:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

void window_quit(GtkWidget *window, int *v) 
{
        g_print("%d\n", *v);
        gtk_main_quit();
}

void normal_function(int *v) 
{
        g_print("%d\n", *v);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        gtk_init(&argc, &argv);
        GtkWidget *window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
        gtk_widget_show(window);
        int v = 5;
        normal_function(&v);
        g_signal_connect(window, "delete-event", G_CALLBACK(window_quit), &v);
        gtk_main();
}
```

How can I call a function on exit and pass it correct values? By the way, I don't have this problem with functions called normally or by other signals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your signal handler is not of the correct type for `"delete-event"`. [The reference manual](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWidget.html#GtkWidget-delete-event) for GTK3 specified it needs to be:

```
gboolean
user_function (GtkWidget *widget,
               GdkEvent  *event,
               gpointer   user_data)
```

Yours is obviously not that. The result is likely a bunch of undefined behavior. The corrupt data you see is likely the punning of `GdkEvent` as an `int`. You also don't return any value despite the fact the framework expects your function to return something.

Since `G_CALLBACK` is a cast, and the framework then casts back to the function pointer type it expects, it's *imperative* you get in the habit of reading the manual for the signals you connect. There is no type safety here and the compiler can't catch these types of errors.

Comment: Ok, but how do I call the callback function using `g_signal_connect`? It takes only 4 parameters but I need 5. Or should I use another function?

Comment: @Hanlon - Huh? You don't modify the call to `g_signal_connect`. You modify the return type and arguments of `window_quit`.

Comment: Ok. So, I do not pass `GdkEvent *event` to a callback function? It is done automatically?

Comment: @Hanlon - Yes, the framework does that for you. If you use the same callback for multiple events, you can get the exact event data from `event`.

Comment: I'll add that you should connect to the `destroy` signal to call `gtk_main_quit`, not the `delete-event` one, as they has different semantics and different signatures. `delete-event` if fo when you want to react to the user trying to close the application, using a confirmation dialog for example, or a saving dialog, and they may change their mind about destroying the window or not. On the other hand, `destroy` signal is emitted when the window is really being destroyed. So you may directly use `g_signal_connect(window, "destroy", G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);`

Comment: Read more on [signal signature conventions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48203860/518853) on an answer I made a while back.